# C# Generic Interface, Generic Implements, Typed Method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to get a generic interface with implentation for handling my xml:
**IXmlService**

```
List<T> Load<T>() where T : class;
```

**XmlService**

```
public List<T> Load<T>() where T : class {
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(TicketData)) { return XmlTicketService.LoadInternal(); } // Error: Unable to cast from List<TicketData> to List<T>
```

And the XmlTicketService.LoadInternal() knows the type and should return to Service

```
internal static List<TicketData> LoadInternal() {
    List<TicketData> result = new List<TicketData>();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        delegate {
            try {
                XDocument data = XDocument.Load(_xmlPath);
                var query = (from element in data.Root.Descendants("Ticket")
                             select new TicketData() {
```

Hope u have and advices for me :)

Comment: You've failed to actually ask a question. That being said, using `typeof` against the generic type is generally a code smell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in this case you can just cast, going via `object`:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(TicketData))
{ 
    return (List<T>) (object) XmlTicketService.LoadInternal();
}
```

The `object` cast first basically forces the compiler to treat it as a "normal" cast.

... but personally I think that raises a design smell, where you should probably be creating a generic *interface* with a non-generic method, and implementing `ILoadable<TicketData>` or whatever. Basically your method isn't *really* generic - it has specific handling for specific types, which should always make you question whether your design is really appropriate.

Comment: I tryed the cast already, didn't work. I think, i will redo my design to generic interface and typed implements.

Comment: @user1191900: "Didn't work" isn't exactly descriptive. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Unable to explicit cast List<TicketData> into List<T>

Comment: @user1191900: Hmm... okay, will edit. Try now, with the additional cast to `object` first.

Comment: :) thanks for that, but I followed ur advice and reworked my design. Generic Interface --> typed implementations.